# Google Custom Search Indexing

Tags: google-custom-search

I created a website and integrated Google custom search for my client, as shown here: http://www.chonglap.com/company/company-profile

The issue I have is, Google custom search indexes for the text on the left and top navigation bar also. For instance, when searching for the word "Biseko", a product sold by my client, the first three results are relevant. But result afterwards are shown because the page contains navigation link with the word Biseko in it.

How could I tell custom search to just index the main content in the page and ignore the text on the top and left navigation bar?

Thank you for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<nav>` tag to help engine understand the structure of your page (although this may not guarantee that the content in the sidebar won't be indexed):
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav

The possible reason of why these results appear is that there are not enough results where "biseko" appears in the main content and google "backfills" with the stuff it found, even if less relevant.